# Is it possible to set intervalStyle per session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a migration that alters the database intervalstyle

```
class CreateAvailabilities < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        execute "ALTER DATABASE \"#{connection.current_database}\" SET intervalstyle = 'iso_8601'"
      end
      dir.down do
        execute "ALTER DATABASE \"#{connection.current_database}\" SET intervalstyle = 'postgres'"
      end
    end
    
    create_table :availabilities do |t|
      t.references :user,      null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.datetime   :starts_at, null: false
      t.interval   :duration,  null: false
      t.timestamps             null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to set a intervalStyle per connection session instead of changing it at the database level?

Comment: See [SET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on my comment. It is possible to change the IntervalStyle in a session:

```
show intervalstyle ;
 IntervalStyle 
---------------
 postgres

select '08/11/2020 12:35'::timestamp - now();
       ?column?        
-----------------------
 1 day 04:29:18.247967

set intervalstyle = 'sql_standard';
SET

 select '08/11/2020 12:35'::timestamp - now();
     ?column?     
------------------
 1 4:28:46.583845
```